# What is an Om component?

Tags: clojurescript, om

Consider the following snippet of om code:

```
(fn [data owner]
    (reify
      om/IRender
      (render [_]
        (dom/p nil (:text data)))))
```

**Question:** Is the "Om component" this entire snippet, or is it merely the function's return value of the `(reify ...)` expression?

Comment: For me this is a function that returns an om component (you could see it as a constructor/factory). Not sure why it should matter though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, they are both referred to as the "component". The result of `reify` is the "object-y" thing, so in a sense it should be called the component, but the function is the thing that's named, so it's typically what's worth talking about.

Importantly, though, *neither* of these is a React component. Om creates and manages a React component for you. It's available here as `owner`.

Om Next removes this level of indirection, which helps with the terminology ambiguity a bit:

```
(defui HelloWorld
  Object
  (render [this]
    (dom/div nil "Hello, world!")))

(def hello (om/factory HelloWorld))
```

In this Om Next code, `HelloWorld` is an actual React component class, and its instances (generated with the function `hello`) are actual React component objects.

Comment: The Om Next version seems vastly superior/less confusing. And I thought Om Next and Om were the same thing. I should probably ditch Om completely, and just learn Om Next. Would you agree?

Comment: Yes, I'd say if you're starting from scratch today, you may as well learn Om Next, unless you need it immediately for production use. It's still not released as "production-ready", but it's expected to be within the next month or two (though, of course, software is hard to estimate).